# Survicate React-Native error: cannot find symbol Survicate.Survicate.setWorkspaceKey(workspaceKey);

Tags: android, react-native, cannot-find-symbol

After following the instruction on the document: https://github.com/Survicate/react-native-survicate I got build failed on Android:

```
error: cannot find symbol
Survicate.Survicate.setWorkspaceKey(workspaceKey);
                 ^
  symbol:   variable Survicate
  location: class Survicate
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':survicate_react-native-survicate:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
```

`Info.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Survicate</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>WorkspaceKey</key>
    <string>...</string>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.survicate.surveys.workspaceKey" android:value="..."/>
```

`App.js`

```
import Survicate from '@survicate/react-native-survicate'

const App = () => {
  Survicate.initialize()
  Survicate.invokeEvent('test')
  Survicate.enterScreen('testScreen')
  ...
}
```

on IOS the build is success but Survicate is not working, and I did create a survey on Survicate's panel, and activated it.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release 1.1.1 fixes this issue. Please update the dependency.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific? I don't see a 1.1.1 release, do you mean 1.0.2?
https://github.com/Survicate/react-native-survicate/releases

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Survicate creator! It worked like a charm on both Android and IOS.